# Is there a name for text that's attributed to a character but without a speech bubble/thought bubble/pointer line/other indicator?

Tags: terminology

Example:

[image: Example]

I get that they're asides, thoughts, implications, feelings, etc., but what is the actual visual device/convention called?

Comment: There is no particular name for it. [This blog post](https://yamada10-07.hateblo.jp/entry/20081115/1226751877) calls them *hand-written phrases* and kinda shows how they are used. (*Hand-written/drawn* because it is usually not typed in the original, which is lost in translation or its production).